# My Dataframe contains many columns and my headers are not displaying properly

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plotly, plotly-dash

How do i wrap header names using plotly.I Tried fixing column width as well since i have many columns it does not fit in my HTML page. 
Below is the sample code

```
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly as py
import textwrap

fig.add_trace(
go.Table(
         columnorder= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13], columnwidth=[75,75,800,100,100,200,200,200,200,100,100,100,1900],
    header=dict(
        values=["GEN","L_GEN","NAME","ACH_TITLE","PERF_TITLE","PERS_SALES","G1_ORDERS",
                "TOTAL_TEAM_SALES","CNTRLTEAM_LDRSALES","G1_BR_LDR_SLVR_LDR","G1_GOLD_LDR",
                "G1_BR_EXEC","PERFORMANCE_TITLE_TIPS"],
        font=dict(size=12),
        line_color='grey',
        fill_color=['#f24dae','#f24dae','#f24dae','#f24dae','#f24dae','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5','#4c31f5'],
        font_color='white',
        height=70,
        align="center"
    ),
    cells=dict(
        values=[df5["GEN"],df5["L_GEN"],df5["NAME"],df5["ACH_TITLE"],df5["PERF_TITLE"],df5["PERS_SALES"],df5["G1_ORDERS"],
                df5["TOTAL_TEAM_SALES"],df5["CNTRLTEAM_LDRSALES"],df5["G1_BR_LDR_SLVR_LDR"],df5["G1_GOLD_LDR"],
                df5["G1_BR_EXEC"],df5["PERFORMANCE_TITLE_TIPS"]],
        align = ['center','center','left','center'],
        #align = "center",
        line_color='grey',
        font_color='black',
        #fill_color = 'white',
        fill=dict(color=[df5.COLOR_L,df5.COLOR_L,df5.COLOR_NAME,df5.COLOR_L,df5.COLOR_L,df5.COLOR_PERS,df5.COLOR_US,df5.COLOR_L1,df5.COLOR_L3,df5.COLOR_EL1,df5.COLOR_L]),
        font=dict(size=10)
        )
),row=1,col=1)
```

[Below is the image link of my output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dbSAA.png)

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

With plotly, you have to wrap manually lines with `\n` in your titles.

Example:

```
"CNTRLTEAM\n_LDRSALES"
```

Tell me if it is working!

Comment: Good idea. I just tried this in my simple example and it still was just one line. I tried "\n" and "\\n". <BR> seems to work but it's so not elegant. I think I would probably use a ditionary to customize the headers.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not ideal, as I'm unaware if plotly has a wrap function. But you could replace the...

```
"_" with <BR>
```

Works on simple charts but you'll of coure get a return on every underscore.

Or use a dictionary to create shorter titles.